# Authentication issue with C# connection to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

So I have an application that is trying to use Command.ExecuteScalar, which works perfectly well on a connection with "root" credentials or with my own user credentials, but I have set up another user in workbench called "AgentsHighPriv" and with that it fails.

The connectionstring is the same except for the substitution with the alternative username and password. However this username and password connects in MySql Workbench, what am I overlooking here.

The specific error message is:

> {"Authentication to host 'xxxx' for user 'AgentsHighPriv' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'AgentsHighPriv'@'%' to database 'rbac'"}

Well it seems there is a difference between credentials that I had not grasped. The privileges had some differences; "schema privalges" were the same as for my own user privileges but, the New User did not require admin privileges of any kind, so I did not use the tab and set global privileges. However if on the administrative roles tab I actually select one of the global privalages, - it then authenticates. At least to say it did so when I tested with select, show view, alter, and drop

Yet I have these same privalages set on the Schema Privalages tab!

So this will make it work now but I dont understand the logic - if anybody could explain I would be happy to hear.

Thanks

Comment: Well, maybe you didn't set the permissions for 'AgentsHighPriv'. Can you post a screenshot of AgentHighPriv's permissions?

Comment: One thing that is different on the new user - supposed to be te same profile as my own - is that the schema column on the schema privalges tab is displaying as an * instead of % - although I used the default All Schema (%) choice when setting up the privalages.

Comment: How do I post an image in here? The privalges are exactly as per my personal ones however.